# JavaScript if element is display = block change CSS of another element

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way of changing the CSS of an element if another element is displayed as 'block' using pure JavaScript?

Sorry probably should have said, the display of the element is dependent on whether a button is pressed.

So button press, element1 = display: block; and element2 = opacity: 0.2;
When element1 = display: none; element2 = opacity 1;

Comment: research following topics: how to check if element display is block, how to change element css programmatically with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is you can get the style by using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div id="divid" style="color:red;">
        Test
    </div>
<script>
test();
    function test() {
    var color = document.getElementById("divid").style.color;

        if(color == "red") {
            document.getElementById("divid").style.color = "green";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work?

Comment: I edited my code to the full version that I've used that should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Test</title>
<style>
    #myDiv{
        display:none;
    } 
</style>
<script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    var newElem = document.getElementById("newDiv");
    if(elem.offsetWidth == 0 && elem.offsetHeight == 0){
        newElem.style.color = "red";
    }else{
        newElem.style.color = "green";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">Test</div>
    <div id="newDiv">Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if the element is hidden other div color will be red else green